# How to find the difference between two euler angles in 3D?

Tags: 3d, rotations, angle

More specifically, given angles $a$ and $b$, what is the shortest rotation $c$ such that when applied to $a$, the angle $b$ is the result? Can this solution be found in all cases, and if so, is there a specific algorithm for it? I can't seem to find any resources online that make the answer obvious, if even give one.

Comment: My first guess would be to convert from euler angles to quats or rotation matrices, then find the difference between those -- for matrices it'd be something like applying the inverse of one to the other, though I'm not sure in which order.  Then you'd have to back out the matrixizing.  Euler angles themselves seem pretty bad to work with for this though.  Also note that this will of course be noncommutative.  ...heh.  I googled this to see if there was a good resource and *this very question* was the first hit.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, there are almost no online resources that even mention this problem, and it seems so simple and universal! It's baffling that nobody has a concrete answer.

Comment: What order you use to rotate the axes? Yaw-Pitch-Roll AKA Body 1-2-3 AKA lab 1-2-3? The [conversion formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Conversion) shown at the Wikipedia page do work for that case (I recently checked), and I can explain the process in detail. However, there are dozens of different Euler angle conventions -- it is a *family* of description methods, not any specific single method; that alone makes using them difficult and *very confusing* -- and I wager that's the reason for the lack of specific examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two rotations, $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$, and we want to find the rotation $\mathbf r$ such that applying $\mathbf p$ and then $\mathbf r$ is equivalent to applying $\mathbf q$.

In quaternions or full-strength rotation matrices, this is easy: $\mathbf q = \mathbf {rp}$, so $\mathbf r = \mathbf q\mathbf p^{-1}$.

Converting between quaternions and Euler angles is another problem, and of course depends on what form of Euler angles you're using.  Wikipedia's got a page literally named [Conversion between quaternions and Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) that looks pretty promising.

Comment: Are $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ rotation matrices here? I am confused, aren't quaternions vectors?

Comment: they could be quaternions or rotation matrices; a quaternion isn't a vector per se, it doesn't act like one, it's a "number".  In any case, you want to use something that isn't Euler angles, because Euler angles are nasty to actually do math with, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering what $\mathbf{p}^{-1}$ would mean for a quaternion however.

Comment: oh.  quaternions have a natural multiplicative inverse; for unit quaternions, which is what is used for spatial rotation, that is simply $\mathbf p ^ {-1} = \mathbf  p^*$, the conjugate, where you simply take the negative of each of the non-real components.  Good thing too, because if you intend to do rotation with raw quaternions you have to multiply by both the original and inverse, $\mathbf x' = \mathbf{qxq}^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.